# Animation.save does not save all frames in matplotlib

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I have the following code to animate plot:

```
# Creating the Animation object
line_ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=generate(), fargs=(lines,),
                                   interval=5, blit=False)

#plt.show()
line_ani.save("animation.mp4")
```

`generate` function yields data and `update` function set this data onto the plot.

When I run this script with `plt.show()` I see very slow and long animation.

When I run this script with `line_ani.save("animation.mp4")` it ends very soon and produces very short animation inside `mp4` file.

Why and how to fix?

**UPDATE**

Although script runs without any errors, PyCharms is reporting a warning:

[image]

> Expected type 'Optional[int]', got 'Generator[...

Comment: *"Why and how to fix?"* How would anyone know without you providing a [mcve] of the issue?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest for example, if there is an obvious missing in presented code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue - you can fix it by supplying the 'FuncAnimation' function with a 'save_count' argument, which tells the function the number of frames it should save (i.e., the number of frames you want to animate). I don't know why this argument is in the 'FuncAnimation' and not in the .save() method...